# Android - Kill intent after some period of time

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am new at Android and working on a speech to text app. I am using Google API. I want to allow users can only speak 2 seconds. After 2 seconds pop-up window should close.  Can anyone give me some tips?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });
}

public void promptSpeechInput()
{
    //This intent recognize the speech
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say Something");

    try {
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your device does not support",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//For receiving speech input
public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent i)
{
    super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

    switch (request_code)
    {
        case 100: if(result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null)
        {
            ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            resultTEXT.setText(result.get(0));
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code where you want to start the timer and in method run you have to write the code for closing the pop up

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code here
        }
    }, 
    5000 
);
```

Here it is 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) you can change it to whatever time period you required in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try Handler inside UIThread this lets you delay when the pop-up window closes..add the code to close the pop-up in run():

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //close the window pop-up here
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```

hope it helps

Comment: you should provide some information or description about your answer and what do you want to solve with your code a little explanation.